# The custom tool 'msdiscocodegenerator' failed

Tags: asp.net, web-services, compact-framework

I get this error when attempting to reference a Web Service in my Compact Framework application. Hunting through Google seems to indicate it's a common occurance, but there's been no useful suggestions as to what causes it, and how to fix it. I can successfully access the web service from a WinForms application by adding a **Service Reference** but the CF project only has the **Web Reference** option.

I am running Visual Studio 2008 on Vista.

Has anybody actually solved this problem after encountering it?

Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe yes... I forget as it was over a year ago. I needed to use a WCF service (presented as a web service) on CF 2.0 device. But I had issues with generating the wrapper.

What I think I did in the end was do it on the desktop and then copy that generated code into the device project. I had to remove a few bits to get CF compatability but it worked in the end.

Sorry for being so vague but my memory is like that sometimes. :)

Comment: I discovered that copying the project to an XP machine, adding the web reference, and then copying the project back to the Vista machine solved the problem!?!

Comment: Do, what, eh? Bizarre. I personally gave up with Vista as it gave me serious grief when trying to work with a DataLogic unit (and its usb driver).

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been identified as BUG from Microsoft and fixed in latest version of visual studio. you can install VS 2013 and try. It was working properly after I upgrade my Visual Studio to 2013 version.